# Is there a way to disable fontScaling for items listed in the react-native-dropdown-picker?

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components, react-native-dropdown-picker

I have tried everything I could find in relation to this particular problem but nothing seems to work.

Tried wrapping the component in a view(long shot manic attempt atp) and disabling fontScaling, still nothing.

I understand there are accessibility concerns with this approach, but I am having troubles getting them item to maintain its visibility within the component. so I am open to all alternatives you might have.

Here's my code below:

```
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

 return (
        <View style={{}} allowFontScaling={false}>
            <DropDownPicker
                placeholder={placeholder}
                open={open}
                value={value}
                items={items}
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: name != 'contactExpert' ? '#EAE3E1' : '#f9fafb',
                    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
                }}
                // textStyle={{ 
                //     allowFontScaling: false,
                // }}
                autoScroll={true}

                dropDownContainerStyle={{
                    borderColor: "lightgrey",

                }}
                allowFontScaling={false}
                onOpen={() => handleFlashScrollIndicator()}
                itemSeparator={true}
                itemSeparatorStyle={{
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "lightgrey",
                    allowFontScaling: false

                }}
                listItemContainerStyle={{
                    alignContent: "center",
                    backgroundColor: name === 'contactExpert' ? 'seashell' : '#fff',
                    allowFontScaling: false

                }}
                listItemLabelStyle={{
                    color: 'black',
                    allowFontScaling: false,
                    adjustsFontSizeToFit: false,

                }}
                dropDownDirection="BOTTOM"
                scrollViewProps={{
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
                    ref: scrollViewRef,
                    persistentScrollbar: true,
                    allowFontScaling: false

                }}
                selectedItemLabelStyle={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    allowFontScaling: false


                }}
                selectedItemContainerStyle={{
                    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
                    allowFontScaling: false

                }}

                setOpen={setOpen}
                setValue={setValue}
                setItems={setItems}
                onSelectItem={(item) => { handleDropDownChange(item) }}
                renderSeperator={() => {
                    return (
                        <Text allowFontScaling={false}>{" "}</Text>
                    );
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
```